# varnish redirect to home web dir

Tags: reverse-proxy, varnish

I have a reverse proxy I'm setting up as an office dashboard with a couple of web hosts behind it. Ultimately I want:

```
dashboard.company/nagios to go to nagios.company/

dashboard.company/grafana to go to grafana.company/
```

I set up the following VCL:

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "80";
}  
backend nagios {
  .host = "10.8.1.14";
  .port = "80";
}
backend grafana {
  .host = "10.8.3.88";
  .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
if (req.url ~ "^/grafana") {
    unset req.http.proxy;
    set req.backend = grafana;
    return (pass);
} elsif (req.url ~ "^/nagios") {
    unset req.http.proxy;
    set req.backend = nagios;
    return (pass);
} else {
    set req.backend = default;
}
}
```

But when I attempt to go to http://dashboard.company:6081/grafana, it's passing the "grafana" URL bit to the backend. I want the request to go to the sourcehost webdir and not sourcehost/grafana. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove first level of URL and pass requests to respective backend by using `set req.backend_hint` instead of `set req.backend`, like so:

```cpp
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
}  
backend nagios {
    .host = "10.8.1.14";
    .port = "80";
}
backend grafana {
    .host = "10.8.3.88";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/grafana") {
        unset req.http.proxy;
        set req.backend_hint = grafana;
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/grafana", "/");
        return (pass);
    } elsif (req.url ~ "^/nagios") {
        unset req.http.proxy;
        set req.backend_hint = nagios;
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^/nagios", "/");
        return (pass);
    } else {
        set req.backend = default;
    }
}
```

Essentially this means that all URLs under `/nagios` will be delivered from root (`/`) of `nagios` backend and all URLs under `/grafana` will be delivered from root (`/`) of `grafana` backend.